# Ошибка ESlint (TypeError: this.cliEngineCtor is not a constructor)

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, eslint

скачал create-react-app с оф. репозитория, открыл проект в VSCode, запустил, ошибок линтера нет, но в PhpStorm 2020.2.4 запустил - работает, но выдает ошибку, скрины приложил, никаких изменений кроме App.js не делал
[image: Код ошибки]

[image: версия линтера в node modules]

[image: package.js]

[image: вид App.js]

[image: настройки линтера в phpstorm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint@8.x поддерживается начиная с версии 2021.2.2, см. [WEB-52236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52236). Попробуйте обновить PHPStorm

Comment: а если не хочется обновлять? стоит лицензия бесплатная(после года подписки) как понизить версию?

Comment: боюсь, в случае приложения, созданного create-react-app простого способа нет. Можно поискать версию create-react-app, которая при создании приложения тащила бы eslint@7

Comment: @Anario может поискать способ обновить только  линтер для PHPStorm?

Comment: @Anario хотя стоп, что в PHPStorm нельзя указать что юзать(локальный конфиг для проекта)? типо юзай вот этот линтер из node_modules вместо того что у тебя вшито?